# Bug ao utilizar pseudo-elemento after em telas pequenas

Tags: css, html5, pseudo-elementos

Olá, um bug curioso apareceu quando tentei fazer um texto com esse efeito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é em telas menores, o segundo efeito no texto **"adipiscing elit!"** simplesmente some, dependendo do tamanho os dois somem, como mostrado na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **ALTERAÇÃO**: Análisando eu percebi que o problema é a quebra da palavra com o efeito, Será que existe alguma maneira de contornar isto?

Abaixo vai o exemplo do código.

> Para reproduzir basta diminuir a *viewport* do seu navegador.

```css
.color-primary {
    color: #225cbe;
}

.featured-text {
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 900;
}

.featured-text:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35%;
    background-color: #fdd104;
    z-index: -10;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-title">
  <p class="color-primary ">
    <span class="featured-text">
      Lorem Ipsum,
    </span> dolor amit.
  </p>

  <p class="color-primary">
    Consectetur, 
    <span class="featured-text">
      adipiscing elit!
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema é que quando a linha quebre o pseudo elemento perde a referência. Encontrei duas formas de resolver, porém não sei se vai ser o ideal para vc.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A primeira é clocando `display:inline-block` no `span` e a outra é uma técnica menos elegante, usando um `&nbsp` para "preencher" o espaço entre uma palavra e outra, e usando a classe em cada uma das palavras...

Veja como fica o comportamento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código que usei:

```css
.color-primary {
  color: #225cbe;
}

.featured-text {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.featured-text:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35%;
  background-color: #fdd104;
  z-index: -10;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-title">
  <p class="color-primary ">
  <span class="featured-text">
    Lorem Ipsum,
  </span> dolor amit.
  </p>

  <p class="color-primary">
  Consectetur, 
  <span class="featured-text" style="display:inline-block;">
    adipiscing elit!
  </span>
  </p>
  <p class="color-primary">
  Consectetur, 
  <span class="featured-text">
    adipiscing</span><span class="featured-text">
      &nbsp</span><span class="featured-text"> elit!
  </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Utilizei o 'inline-block' como é um projeto que não vai demorar muito não vou precisar me preocupar com tantos detalhes.

Comment: @MSLacerda é uma solução funcional, mas ainda não é a solução perfeita, isso é se existe uma solução perfeita rss. Mas no teste que eu fiz, se a tela for extremamente pequena, ainda corre o risco de buggar, acredito que não vai ser o seu caso... Até pq se for um texto extenso dentro desse span vai dar pau mesmo com o `inline-block`... Particularidades do CSS :/

Comment: Acredito eu que não tenha uma solução perfeita, até pq fazer esse efeito no texto apenas com css requer esses "hacks" e isso por si só já é um problema, mas o texto é pequeno mesmo e só aparece uma vez, então essa solução alternativa vai solucionar.